# React Native Can't Import Component "Undefined is not a function"

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo, importerror, react-component

I am trying to import this component from github into my code: (https://github.com/bibekg/react-schedule-selector). However, it's not registering when I run expo and I get this error:
[Undefined is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdYy7.png)

Here is my code:

```
import ScheduleSelector from "react-schedule-selector/src/lib";

export default function ({ navigation }) {
    const [schedule, setSchedule] = React.useState([]);
    return (
        <Layout>
            <TopNav
                leftContent={<Ionicons name="chevron-back" size={20} color={"black"} />}
                leftAction={() => navigation.navigate("Me")}
                middleContent="Schedule"
            />
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                }}
            >
                <Text>https://github.com/bibekg/react-schedule-selector</Text>
                <ScheduleSelector
                    selection={schedule}
                    numDays={5}
                    minTime={8}
                    maxTime={22}
                    hourlyChunks={2}
                    onChange={(val) => setSchedule(val)}
                />
            </View>
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

Also, I have already run npm install react-schedule-selector styled-components on my computer!

Any ideas on why this error is occurring and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: `import ScheduleSelector from 'react-schedule-selector'` use this

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```js
import ScheduleSelector from "react-schedule-selector/src/lib";
```

is not correct. You need to change it to the following.

```js
import ScheduleSelector from 'react-schedule-selector'
```

This is documented [here](https://github.com/bibekg/react-schedule-selector).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I made your edits but unfortunately it's throwing a new error now. Is there a dependency I forgot to install somewhere?
here is the error:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pEyhsVWWV6drf_Wk-Y9AH4XyKNM5cvxd/view?usp=sharing